# <a> tag making whole div clickable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've created a col-md-3 div in Bootstrap and placed an `<a>` tag within to make some `<img>` clickable. The problem now is the whole div is click-able, not just the img.

code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"> 
    <img id="logo" class="img-responsive" src="http://themes.tielabs.com/jarida/wp-content/themes/jarida/images/logo.png" alt="" />
  </a> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-md-3{
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Please provide help.

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: And css? Maybe your div is floated (as all `col-*` are floated) and it's taking full width/height of inner elements?

Comment: Your CSS isn't correct. There is no selector.

Comment: Selector is added now

Comment: As in http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/c882F/ , i can only click on image. So i think you have some other css, that applies to this link/div/image

Answer (score 3):

Make sure there is no outer padding... most of your styles would be on the `<a>`... `a {display:block;}` will make that container stretch to the size of the container div (`col-md-3`) as long as there is no padding on it or anything in it that is making the size larger. Basically, do what you have to to make the container only as bg as the `<a>`